# Concatenate WAV audio files with FFmpeg and preserve bit depth

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to concatenate two WAV audio files with FFmpeg. However the resulted output was only 16 bit depth whereas the inputs where 24 bit depth. How can I retain the bit depth?

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i ZOOM0001.WAV -i ZOOM0002.WAV -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out]' -map '[out]' output1.wav
```

And this:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:ZOOM0001.WAV|ZOOM0002.WAV" output2.wav
```

Coping the codec with `-c copy` as explained in the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) did not work well also and resulted with a large file with the first audio only; the second audio part did not play.

Answer (score 3):

The default codec for WAV output is `pcm_s16le`. You need to specify a 24-bit codec.

`ffmpeg -i ZOOM0001.WAV -i ZOOM0002.WAV -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out]' -map '[out]' -c:a pcm_s24le output1.wav`

Comment: Thanks for `pcm_s24le` point specifically. It saved my days